# Creating the correct media query breakpoints to cover mobile and tablet

Tags: html, css, mobile, media-queries

Basically I'm building a site that requires 2 media queries, 1 that will cover mobile and another that will cover tablet. That's the requirements.

The problem I have is this for mobile the max-width would have to be 640px to cover Samsung Galaxy S3 but for tablet the Nexus 7 max-width in portrait is 599 so I run the risk of my phone falling into the tablet query.

Can anyone advise how i can get round this?

Answer (score 3):

You can apply this settings. It works well (at least for me):

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. I've tried all possible media queries. In order to differentiate tablets and phones you have to use `max-device-width` media query with physical dimensions, not the one with pixels width.

Here is excerpt of my CSS used to target tablets in landscape orientation, please take a look at the `max-device-width`:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (orientation: portrait),
screen and (max-device-width: 23cm) and (orientation: landscape),
screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-device-width: 1280px) and (max-device-height: 1000px)
```

I have used this query on iPad (non-retina), iPad 2 (retina) and ASUS Transformer tablet. Specifying size in `cm` works just fine, inches `in` were not working on some tablets (can't recall which ones at the moment).

Reference to official description of `max-device-width` media query: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/#device-width

Answer (score 0):

see this for mobile and tablet: 
you can find the correct size on the actual device if you run it in a test page.

https://jsfiddle.net/t2bybrdu/

html:

```
<div class="body-test">
      <div class="center green-btn">Browser size tester:</div>
      </br>
      </br>
      <div class="result"></div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".body-test .center").click(function(){
    var browser_size = $( window ).width();
    console.log( browser_size + 20);
    console.log( "viewport size: " + Number(20 + browser_size) );
    $(".body-test .result").text("Your viewport size is: " + Number(browser_size + 20) + "px");     
});
```

css:

```
.green-btn {
    display: block;
    background: green;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 180px;
}
.body-test {
    padding-top: 120px;

}
.body-test  .result {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 3em auto;
}

.body-test  .center {
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50% - 100px); 
    cursor: pointer;
}
```